# Underlining an entire row in a table

Tags: html, css

My HTML/CSS code below works great for underlining the text in a single table cell when the mouse hovers over it but I'd like it to underline all the text in row of cells, not just the single cell. I don't need it to underline the entire row with a single line -- a line under each text item would be fine, though a single line would work too if that's easier.

I thought changing the a: to tr: would do the trick, but it had no effect.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Project Index</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    a:link {text-decoration:none;}
    a:hover {text-decoration: underline; }

    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">
   Project Index</h2>
  <h3 style="text-align: center;">
   2013-06-11 18:44</h3>
  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" height="29" width="728" style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">
      Project
      <hr />
     </th>
     <th scope="col">
      Activity
      <hr />
     </th>
     <th scope="col">
      Items
      <hr />
     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">
      <a style="color:#0000cd;" href="C:\Users\Caterpillar\Google Drive\SPDA\Standards\Project Reports\Full Reports\Test Project 1.html">Test Project 1 </a></th>
     <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">
      <a style="color:#0000cd;" href="C:\Users\Caterpillar\Google Drive\SPDA\Standards\Project Reports\Full Reports\Test Project 1.html">2013-06-09 17:31</a></th>
     <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">
      <a style="color:#0000cd;" href="C:\Users\Caterpillar\Google Drive\SPDA\Standards\Project Reports\Full Reports\Test Project 1.html">RFI:5 CCO:2 </a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">
      <a style="color:#0000cd;" href="C:\Users\Caterpillar\Google Drive\SPDA\Standards\Project Reports\Full Reports\Test Project 2.html">Test Project 2 </a></th>
     <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">
      <a style="color:#0000cd;" href="C:\Users\Caterpillar\Google Drive\SPDA\Standards\Project Reports\Full Reports\Test Project 2.html">2013-06-06 09:06</a></th>
     <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">
      <a style="color:#0000cd;" href="C:\Users\Caterpillar\Google Drive\SPDA\Standards\Project Reports\Full Reports\Test Project 2.html">RFI:2 </a></th>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added an update to my solution that will make it work in IE as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this style:

```
tr a {text-decoration:none;}
tr:hover a {text-decoration: underline;}
```

**UPDATE** To make this work in IE you have to include DOCTTYPE in your markup. Add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Before

```
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
tr:hover a {text-decoration: underline; }
```

This is because the text-decoration should be applied to the a-tags in the hovered row.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `tr:hover` in the CSS selector, however this doesn't work in very old browsers (IE7 and down for example).

```
tr:hover a { text-decoration: underline; }
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/agasih/1

In the demo, I have changed the data rows in your table to the more appropriate `<td>` element.

Comment: Thanks to all that proposed the above format. It wasn't working for me on IE 10, but when I tried on Firefox, it worked great. Any suggestions to make it work on IE 10?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript solution if you need support for older IEs.

http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/